# Why my code is printing double "k" at the final? AutoHotKey (ahk)

Tags: autohotkey

```
fly := True 

Start()
    {
        Global fly
        fly := True
        While (fly == True)
            {
                Send, {Shift down}{W down}
                Sleep, 10
            }
    }

End()
    {
        Global fly
        fly := False
        Send, {Shift up}{W up}
    }

MButton::
Send, {K}
Start()

+XButton2::
Send, {K}
End()

Return
```

I don't know why, but everytime i stop the program it prints a double "k" at the final and i have no clue why is this happening, could someone point me where is the error? thank you very much!! ^v^

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `Return`s to stop code execution.
Every hotkey label is to be ended with a `Return` so it doesn't bleed through to something unwanted (in your case, to the next hotkey label).

Your [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) is also bleeding through, but in this instance it doesn't matter, since the code-execution encounters just functions before being stopped by a hotkey label.

Also, using [SendInput](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is recommended over just normal Send.
And wrapping `K` in `{ }` does nothing for you, and it could even result in undesired behavior in special cases (read the documentation for this).
Wrapping a character in `{ }` is only to be done for escaping characters with special meaning in a send command, such as `+` (shift) or `!` (Alt) (also read the documentation for a full explanation on this).

---

Here's an example of adding those missing `Return`s to your script:

```
fly := True 
return

Start()
{
    Global fly
    fly := True
    While (fly == True)
    {
        SendInput, {Shift down}{W down}
        Sleep, 10
    }
}

End()
{
    Global fly
    fly := False
    SendInput, {Shift up}{W up}
}

MButton::
    SendInput, K
    Start()
Return

+XButton2::
    SendInput, K
    End()
Return
```

Comment: Thank you man, i'll make sure to read the documentation , but thank you anyway ^v^